# What is the use case for `Interlocked.SpeculationBarrier` in C#?

Tags: c#, speculative-execution

There is a new function `Interlocked.SpeculationBarrier` since .net framework 4.8. I have been curious and looking for more information about this but couldn't really find out why this is included or why you would want to block speculative execution. So what is the use case for this?

Would enabling this make your application more secure when handling sensitive information against vulnerabilities that target speculative execution(ex. spectre, meltdown)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.speculationbarrier?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Check out this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31639#issuecomment-581201581 - in short, it's fairly useless.

Comment: [Related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31639)

Comment: Looks like it was .NET's answer to the Meltdown and [Spectre vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)).  Which caused a lot of panic but no documented practical vulnerabilities.